# Azure API - How do I setup CORS

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have REST API, that is hosted in Azure. If I make request in interactive console with GET method  ('/api/pets'), request goes through just fine. But when I make POST request (POST '/api/pets'), CORS error appears.

Response in interacive console throws this error:
[image: Response in interacive console throws this error]

startup.cs

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        
            .
            .
            .

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                }));
            .
            .
            .
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

All API's CORS policy

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
                <method>PUT</method>
                <method>DELETE</method>
                <method>HEAD</method>
                <method>OPTIONS</method>
                <method>PATCH</method>
                <method>TRACE</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>
```

I also tried setting CORS policy on azure portal only in specific API, but it doesn't work
Everything works fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies#example-1) this using the portal?

1. Open your API in the Azure API Management section of the Azure portal
2. Select All operations, or a single operation
3. On the right, choose Inbound processing > Add policy
4. You will get a list of prefab policy templates. Choose the "CORS" one and configure it at will:

UPDATE:

Can you modify the XML as below

```
 <cors>
     <allowed-origins>
        <origin>*</origin>
     </allowed-origins>
     <allowed-methods>
        <method>*</method>
      </allowed-methods>
         <allowed-headers>
      <header>*</header>
         </allowed-headers>
       <expose-headers>
           <header>*</header>
       </expose-headers>
  </cors>
```

Comment: I already tried this, and it doesn't work. It sets policy as seen in question.

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago I tried Outboud rules into API Managment Policies to add this headers to response:

```html
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <cors allow-credentials="true">
      ...
    </cors>
  </inbound>
    ...
  <outbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
      <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Origin",""))</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" exists-action="override">
      <value>true</value>
    </set-header>
  </outbound>
   ...
</policies>
```

Also make sure that you are using `app.UseCors()` before response compression if exists and before `app.UseEndpoints()` or `app.UseMvc()`